# SSJS Rows.Retrieve not working as expected in CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

Trying to debug SSJS code in CloudPages and ran into the following exception.

> {"message":"Object expected: Retrieve","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: Retrieve\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

Following is the code

```
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
  try {
      var FTCodesDE = DataExtension.Init("Free_Trial_Codes");
      var filter = {
          Property: "Email",
          SimpleOperator: "equals",
          Value: "daniel@example.com.sg"
      };
      var data = FTCodesDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
      console.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using preview for your cloudpage? Can you try setting it live?

Recently, there was news that preview behavior of cloudpages is now similar to Emails: [Problem using Subscriber | WSProxy inside a CloudPage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340455/problem-using-subscriber-wsproxy-inside-a-cloudpage)

The documentation for Rows.Retrieve says that
"The Retrieve function cannot be used in the context of an email message or email preview."

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsRetrieve.htm

Comment: Indeed. I was using preview and it caused the error. Publishing the page resolved it