# UpsertDE not working in cloud page using ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, authentication, cloudpage

I have this code and I want to store the data of auth API into a data extension.
I am able to successfully generate the result of API but not able to store that data in a data extension.

You can see my code below:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")
    var str = Variable.GetValue("@JSON");
    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(str);
    var token = obj.access_token;
    var auth = 'Bearer ' + token;
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest("https://api.socialstudio.radian6.com/v3/users/me");
        req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
        req.retries = 2;
        req.continueOnError = true;
        req.contentType = "application/json"
        req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
        req.method = "GET";
    var resp = req.send();
    var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
    var item = resultJSON.data[0];
    Write(item['id']);
    var row = Platform.Function.UpsertDE("Auth_API", ["id"], [item['id']], ["username"], [item['username']]);
</script>
```

The `UpsertDE` function is not working and is showing this error while loading the cloud page: **500 - Internal server error**.

I have checked the Attributes and the Data Extension name and they are the same.

Comment: have you tried to debug this in emailstudio to get better error messages? Do you have non nullable fields in the DE?

Comment: Give putting a try... catch around your code a go and take a look at the nature of the error.

Comment: Can you share an example output of `item`? to make sure that the JSON structure matches? Have you validated that the outputs are as expected? Writing both id and username values? Have you put these into a var and pushed into the function rather than have them raw inside the array? Have you run it without the upsert function to validate it is 100% that function?

Comment: Also - long story short on the Answers below around UpsertDE and UpsertData - the recommendation would be to use UpsertData on a CP or LP as it is optimized in this environment and as the functions are 100% identical, it is not a huge lift to implement. But neither of these would cause a 500 error - so not likely to be the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `UpsertDE` method can be used in sendable contexts, such as email messages.

`UpsertData` should be used in non-sendable contexts, such as landing pages.

---

UpsertData:

"Updates or inserts information into a data extension as indicated by the array containing the listed column name and value pairs. This method adds the information if the data extension does not contain an applicable value or updates the existing applicable value to the new value. You can include multiple column name and value parts in a single call. You can use this method in non-sendable contexts, such as landing pages. This call returns the number of rows modified."

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertData.htm

---

UpsertDE:

Updates or inserts information into a data extension as indicated by the array containing the listed column name and value pairs. This method adds the information if the data extension does not contain an applicable value or updates the existing applicable value to the new value. You can include multiple column name and value parts in a single call. You can use this method in sendable contexts, such as email messages.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertDE.htm

Comment: I answered this question with the same suggestion and it is not the case as @LukasLunow corrected me because you can use both SSJS functions on the landing page. Try it out yourself.

Comment: @Niko I just tested both. UpsertData worked and UpsertDE did not. I have not seen any evidence that UpsertDE works on cloudpages. Can you share a link to that?

Comment: Hello @jake314159, I said that since I have tested as well and even re-tested now and it worked again with `UpsertDE` in CloudPage. I do not think it is documented (at least I did not find anything). Here is a short video showing the results from my end - https://www.loom.com/share/72b304c128cb47ce824cb192cf8def26 :) I do wonder why our results differ though...

Comment: @Niko, from your video it looks like the UpsertDE is running when you first preview/publish the page, not when you visit the page itself. I'd recommend outputting the result of the UpsertDE/UpsertData on the page (not just any possible errors with try/catch) so you can see the result of the function call on the page. The preview of cloudpages will process the code differently than the actual page.

You can prevent your code from running in the Preview w/this AMPscript: 

`%%[if indexof(requestparameter('pageurl'),'cloudPages/preview') < 1 then]%%`

(could also be written in SSJS)

Comment: Nope, it actually adds a record when I am visiting the page, I have checked this point already. Also, it is mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340455/problem-using-subscriber-wsproxy-inside-a-cloudpage) that the Preview feature of the CloudPage does not execute the code anymore as it was before.

Comment: Your video does not prove that the code was executed on the page itself. The preview definitely does attempt to execute the code, as proven in your video when it errored when trying the UpsertData. If you actually output the result of your UpsertDE and UpsertData, you would see this.

Comment: Such disbelief, I am not trolling you or lying. As I said, preview is actually throwing errors after a recent release but not executing the code... check this [video](https://www.loom.com/share/fec4c77d19b8447ba1690aac765ca0a5) out as proof, sometimes things are working as you are not expecting them to.

Comment: No need to get personal. An easy way to prove this out is if you preview/publish the page with an UpsertDE and then without going the page itself, check the data extension. Or write the pageURL to the DE as well. Every instance in your video does not do that. Not sure why you are against outputting the result of your function call either, since that would provide feedback into what is happening where.

Comment: Plus, in your most recent video, the URL and context is output in preview, so that proves the code is running in preview

Comment: Check the video and the code inside again... when I am publishing the page, URL contains `/preview/` part and thus it says "Publish". Once I open the page, it says "View" because the page has been published and the URL does not contain `/preview/` part. As I told you already, some of your checks (e.g. publish the page and check DE) I have done already several times and they are not proving your point, it is your decision to really not believe, and at this point, there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: We work with code. There is no belief involved. Your video left gaps in the process that could have resulted in the data being placed in the DE in a different way than you intended.

UpsertData should be used on pages since the function returns the number of affected rows, which can be used in further scripts. UpsertDE returns nothing. I suspect UpdateDE working in a non-sendable context is a bug, and you should not use a bug as a solution.

Please drop the personal comments moving forward. This is not the place for that.